# how to create the bitmap from intptr

Tags: c#-4.0, bitmap, avi, intptr

i am making a video stegnaography project, in which I got the clone of the selected frames from the video and then I have to replace these embedded frames with the real frames in the video. I have used the `avifile` library so far and i use the `cut function` in the avi library. The cut function actually cut the a video stream of the given length but I have to cut on frame at a time. The function returns a intptr. I tried to make a bitmap from that intptr by using over loaded bitmap constructor. I am using c#.

```
 p = editableStream.Cut(156, 157);
 Bitmap b = new Bitmap(300, 300, 400, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, p);
```

when i try to save the bitmap then it show the exception ...`A generic error occurred in GDI+.`

```
 b.Save(@"D:\MCS _2\New folder\aaaa.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: The EditStreamCut() function doesn't return a bitmap at all.  You get a handle to a new avi stream.  So of course this code can't work.

Comment: @HansPassant what should i do to replace the frame in the video..